# Query performance issue using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following records in view:

```
 coldate                coltime           colseconds
------------------------------------------------------
 2014-08-02     1900-01-01 10:00:00.000      50
 2014-08-02     1900-01-01 11:08:08.000      120
 2014-08-02     1900-01-01 11:08:55.000      160
 2014-08-03     1900-01-01 09:00:15.000      180
 2014-08-04     1900-01-01 11:00:10.000      600
 2014-08-04     1900-01-01 11:05:50.000      320
```

And the Expected Result is:

```
 coldate                coltime           colseconds
------------------------------------------------------
 2014-08-02     1900-01-01 11:08:08.000      120
 2014-08-02     1900-01-01 11:08:55.000      160
 2014-08-04     1900-01-01 11:00:10.000      600
 2014-08-04     1900-01-01 11:05:50.000      320
```

For which I am using the following script:

```
 declare @testtable table(dt date,st time,et time)

 insert into @testtable select coldate,coltime,DATEADD(ss,colseconds,coltime) from testt

 select distinct coldate,
            coltime,colseconds from (
 SELECT x.* FROM
 (
    select distinct coldate,
            coltime,colseconds from testt as x  /* testt is the view*/
            inner join  
            @testtable  as t on
            CAST(x.coltime as time) > t.st and CAST(x.coltime as time) < t.et 
  )x 
  UNION all

  SELECT  testt.coldate,
            testt.coltime,testt.colseconds FROM
  (
          select distinct coldate,
            coltime,colseconds,t.st  from testt as x 
            inner join  
            @testtable  as t on
            CAST(x.coltime as time) > t.st and CAST(x.coltime as time) < t.et 
  )y
 INNER JOIN  testt ON y.st = CAST(testt.coltime as time) 
 )z
```

And Yes I have tried with `temp table` with an index and `testt` is the view name but still taking huge time:

```
 create TABLE #testtable (dt date,st time,et time)

 create index index_st_et_dt on #testtable(dt,st,et)
```

**Note**:But getting a huge time for a huge data.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You should edit the question and describe what you want the query to do.

Comment: How much time does it cost when querying the view? I am not seeing performance issue in your query as there are only 6 records and the query should go fast. The only possible reason I could figure is the performance in view...

Comment: @zhongxiao37, Yes you right! But issue is not for the small set of records. But for huge around 50k records this is going above 10 min.

Comment: @zhongxiao37, Is there any alternative way to write script which does the same job? Thanks

Comment: @Meem: The most obvious alternative way to write the query would be to use a CTE instead of the table-valued variable.

Comment: @Meem I would suggest you try to improve the performance in your view. Without seeing view scripts & sample table data, we could not help a lot.

Comment: @zhongxiao37, Okay! fine.

Comment: I'd recommend adding this to a sqlfiddle. Also, how is your table defined that the view hits.

Comment: Your a derived table returns a double result. Why do you need this?